# Linq Query Question

Tags: c#, .net, linq

There is standard way to count number of elements which fit some condition:

```
collection.Where(d=> d==something).Count();
```

I need the following functionality (pseudo-cod):

```
collection.Where(d=> (d==something) && (d.Next == somethingElse)).Count();
```

EDIT: d.Next - is the next element after d in the collection.

How this can be achieved?

Comment: Is `d.Next` a property of `d` or the next element in the sequence?

Comment: No, Next is the next element in the collection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that what you have is a predicate that involves consecutive elements in the source-sequence, you can do:

```
int numMatches = collection.Zip(collection.Skip(1), (prev, next) =>
                                prev == something && next == somethingElse)
                           .Count(match => match)
```

This overlays the sequence on a one-deferred version of the sequence before applying the filter.

Comment: That is simple and elegant. Thanks!

Comment: I really like this solution, however I think it enumerates the `IEnumerable` twice due to the combination of zip/skip. This can lead to problems with certain implementations of `IEnumerable`. It is safe to use with list-like implementations though.

Answer (score 3):

```
var result = collection.Count(d => 
     d == something && 
     d.Next == somethingElse
);
```

**EDIT:** in the case if `d.Next` a property of `d` or the next element in the sequence:

```
var result = collection.Zip(
    collection.Skip(1),
    (first, second) => first == something && second == somethingElse
).Count(i => i);
```

Comment: I guess the problem is that `d` doesn't have a `Next` property.

Comment: I meant, the Next is the next element in the collection.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a new operator (assuming Linq-to-objects) that checks this using the enumerator explicitly.

**Code:**

```
public static partial class Enumerable
{
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> WhereNext<TSource> (this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate, TSource next)
    {
        if (source == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        if (predicate == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("predicate");

        return WhereNextImpl(source, predicate, next);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<TSource> WhereNextImpl<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate, TSource next)
    {
        using (var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            TSource current;
            TSource nextElement;

            if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
                yield break;
            while (true)
            {
                current = enumerator.Current;
                if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
                    yield break;
                nextElement = enumerator.Current;

                if (predicate(current) && EqualityComparer<TSource>.Default.Equals(next, nextElement))
                    yield return current;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Caveat: Currently uses `EqualityComparer<TSource>.Default` for comparision. Another implementation with a custom comparer should be done.

Comment: It is a little bit complicated, but, perhaps, most effective one.

Comment: also it doesn't enumerate the `IEnumerable` twice, which can be of an advantage.

Answer (score 1):

if collection were List of stirng, you could try something like

```
var selectC = from c in collection
let nextC = collection.IndexOf(c) == collection.Count - 1 ? null : collection[collection.IndexOf(c) + 1]
where string.IsNullOrEmpty(c) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(nextC)
select c;
```

queries involving let are tricky to translate into method chain but I got this from Resharper's automatic conversion

```
var selectC =
    collection.Select(
        c =>
        new {c, nextC = collection.IndexOf(c) == collection.Count - 1 ? null : collection[collection.IndexOf(c) + 1]}).
        Where(@t => string.IsNullOrEmpty(@t.c) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(@t.nextC)).Select(@t => @t.c);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Aggregate Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548744.aspx) to create a custom sum:

```
var result = collection.Aggregate(
    Tuple.Create(false, 0),
    (s, x) => Tuple.Create(x == something,
                           s.Item1 + (s.Item0 && (x == somethingElse) ? 1 : 0)),
    s => s.Item1);
```

---

It works like this:

```
Item            Accumulator
--------------- ---------------
                (false, 0)
foo             (false, 0)
something       (true, 0)
bar             (false, 0)
something       (true, 0)
somethingElse   (false, 1)
somethingElse   (false, 1)
baz             (false, 1)
                ---------------
                Result: 1
```